# Lenovo USB 3.0 to DVI/VGA monitor adapter ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, multiple-monitors, lenovo

I just brought an extra screen and found that I had no spare slots for it. So of course I went out and got a [USB to DVI/VGA adapter](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/itemdetails/0B47072/460/D9D7E3B5E92F40DD9D2CF85459B8AFCB)

In the crate a cd with an exe file on it followed.

Now i have tried to connect my screen with the adapter and my computer however all i get is `no signal` The adapter it self is glowing showing there is a connection between the computer and the adapter.

My question is has anyone tried with these adapters on Ubuntu 14.04 and know a way around so i can make it work?

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bdb:1911 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1532:000e Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 17e9:4311 DisplayLink 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

above is the output of `lsusb`

`usb-devices | awk '/17e9/' RS=` output

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=17e9 ProdID=4311 Rev=01.01
S:  Manufacturer=DisplayLink
S:  Product=Lenovo USB3.0 to DVI Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=10093213
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=03 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output

Comment: Please also add `usb-devices | awk '/17e9/' RS=` output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not supported by Linux yet.

But Lenovo [promised](http://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/7988955-support-linux-on-all-your-devices) to make a driver soon.

The only way to use this device is to install Windows as a virtual machine.
Then you will be able to pass through the USB device and install a Windows driver.

**Update July 17':** Now this device is supported. You can download a driver for Ubuntu from
http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: Do you know of any adapters that would work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: this is a saddest news ever!

Comment: I think it should be supported now. Two years passed since this answer.

Comment: really grateful for the update. I want to buy it now :)

Comment: @holms have you bought have tried it ?

Comment: @TusharGoswami sadly not - post-poned as my 30" monitor needs a fix

Comment: works with ubuntu 20.04, thank you for the link (I didn't even notice the displaylink sticker)